# Sum of a finite series almost like gp

Tags: real-analysis, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $a>1$ and consider the following finite series:
$$
1+\frac{2}{a}+\frac{3}{a^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{a^{n-1}},
$$
where $n\geq 1$ is a fixed quantity.

Then is the above series uniformly bounded by a constant independent of $n$?

I tried to proceed as follows:
We know that
$$
1+\frac{2}{a}+\frac{3}{a^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{a^{n-1}}=\frac{r^{n+1}n+1-(n+1)r^n}{(1-r)^2}
$$
where $r=\frac{1}{a}$.

But unable to proved the independency. Can somebody kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: derivate series $\sum x^n$ with $x=\frac 1a$.

Comment: Yes, the sum of the gp series $1+r+\cdots+r^{n-1}=\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$ for $0<r<1$. Now take derivative with respect to $r$ to obtain the estimate.

Comment: Just show $nr^{n+1} < (n+1)r^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a > 1$ you get that $nr^n \to 0$, thus  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big( 1 + \dots +\frac{n}{a^{n-1}} \Big) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{r^{n+1}n+1-(n+1)r^n}{(1-r)^2} = \frac{1}{(1-r)^2}$$and the sum is bounded by its limit because $$S_n = 1 + \dots + \frac{n}{a^{n-1}}$$
is strictly increasing with respect $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. @Ker